# Random String Program

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to create a program that runs 5-10 lines of random text from a-z. I've tried running this program, but always get a blank console.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
     int numberLines = (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 5);
    for (int b = 0; b <= numberLines; b++) {
         int length = (int) Math.random() * 80;
for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
    int randChar = (int) Math.random() * 26;
    if (randChar == 0) {
        System.out.print("a");
    }
    else if (randChar == 1) {
        System.out.print("b");
    }
    else if (randChar == 2) {
        System.out.print("c");
    }
    else if (randChar == 3) {
        System.out.print("d");
    }
    else if (randChar == 4) {
        System.out.print("e");
    }
    else if (randChar == 5) {
        System.out.print("f");
    }
    else if (randChar == 6) {
        System.out.print("g");
    }
    else if (randChar == 7) {
        System.out.print("h");
    }
    else if (randChar == 8) {
        System.out.print("i");
    }
    else if (randChar == 9) {
        System.out.print("j");
    }
    else if (randChar == 10) {
        System.out.print("k");
    }
    else if (randChar == 11) {
        System.out.print("l");
    }
    else if (randChar == 12) {
        System.out.print("m");
    }
    else if (randChar == 13) {
        System.out.print("n");
    }
    else if (randChar == 14) {
        System.out.print("o");
    }
    else if (randChar == 15) {
        System.out.print("p");
    }
    else if (randChar == 16) {
        System.out.print("q");
    }
    else if (randChar == 17) {
        System.out.print("r");
    }
    else if (randChar == 18) {
        System.out.print("s");
    }
    else if (randChar == 19) {
        System.out.print("t");
    }
    else if (randChar == 20) {
        System.out.print("u");
    }
    else if (randChar == 21) {
        System.out.print("v");
    }
    else if (randChar == 22) {
        System.out.print("w");
    }
    else if (randChar == 23) {
        System.out.print("x");
    }
    else if (randChar == 24) {
        System.out.print("y");
    }
    else if (randChar == 25) {
        System.out.print("z");
    }
    System.out.println();
 }    
}
```

I know there's a way simpler way of doing this, but for my purposes, I'd like to know why this didn't work.

Help?

Comment: think of the ascii table

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question. What are you trying to say?

Comment: If this was meant to be just an exercise, fine. But if all you wanted was a random alphabetic string of a certain size, you're better off using [RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(int)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html#randomAlphabetic(int))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your problem come from the line `int length = (int) Math.random() * 80;`.
This make always `length` equal to 0 as `Math.random()` return a `double` between 0.0 and 1.0, which will be cast to 0 as an `int`.

You can try to add parentheses like that

```
int length = (int) (Math.random() * 80);
```

Comment: Doh! Of course. Thanks so much sonic. See the same problem with int randChar = (int) Math.random() * 26;

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `Math#Random`

> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

So basicly your calculation of `length` allways generates a `0`. The double returned is allways less then `1`. The following cast to `int` will generate a `0` therefore and your second loop is not going to get executed.

The same would happen to the calculation of `randchar`.

To change it you could go with the `Random` class.

```
Random r = new Random();
...
...
int randChar = r.nextInt(26);
```